# CORS Access-Control-Max-Age works for same origin or just same request url

Tags: google-chrome, http, browser, cors

Now we have some CORS request (get, range header)

```
get http://example.com/01.mv (request a1)
get http://example.com/01.mv (request a2)
get http://example.com/02.mv (request b1)
get http://example.com/02.mv (request b2)
```

Before sending request a1, browser will send a OPTIONS request,
and we can find `Access-Control-Max-Age: 3600` in response.

Here is my question:

> in request a2, an OPTIONS request will be sent?
>
> in request b1, an OPTIONS request will be sent?
>
> in request b2, an OPTIONS request will be sent?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Short answer: Browsers apply [`Access-Control-Max-Age`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Max-Age) per-URL, not per-origin.

> in request a2, an OPTIONS request will be sent?

No, because due to the `Access-Control-Max-Age` header for that URL, the browser will have cached the results of the CORS preflight *but only for that `http://example.com/01.mv` URL*.

> in request b1, an OPTIONS request will be sent?

Yes, because it’s for a *different* URL, `http://example.com/02.mv`.

The CORS protocol does preflights per-URL, not per-origin, so the value of that other `Access-Control-Max-Age` for the request `a1` URL doesn’t not apply to the different `b1` URL.

> in request b2, an OPTIONS request will be sent?

No, for the same reason it’s not sent for request `a2`: due to `Access-Control-Max-Age` the browser will have cached the results of the CORS preflight for `http://example.com/02.mv`.

---

As far as what the CORS spec defines as the relevant requirements here, if you trace the steps in the spec they’ll take you to the definition in the spec for the term [**cache match**](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#concept-cache-match):

> There is a **cache match**
> for *request* if origin is *request*’s origin, **url is *request*’s current url…**

In other words, a cached preflight will only be used for a request if *both*:

1. the request’s origin matches the origin for that cached preflight
2. *and* the request’s URL matches the URL for that cached preflight

Comment: why b1 will send an OPTIONS request ? they have the same origin `http://example.com`.

Comment: Because OPTIONS preflights are initiated *per-URL*, not per-origin. Browsers don’t take the preflight results they receive from response for one URL from a particular origin and reuse it for requests for all other URLs from that origin. That wouldn’t make sense. For one thing, the owner of the second URL space may be completely different from the owner of the first URL spec. So the different owners need to have control over the CORS behavior for their own URL space. Etc.