# Cordova page view cache vs $http cache vs CORS preflight caching

Tags: angularjs, cordova, caching, cors, http-headers

I am trying to understand the relationships between the different caching mechanisms or how one cache impacts another cache.  My cordova app talks to my api server - and all works fine.  But in an effort to try to cache CORS preflight so my app isn't constantly hitting the server with preflight requests I saw some odd or unexpected behaviors that I have researched but can't explain.

Cordova app, all of my views are cached.  In my `app.js` my views are defined as such:

```
  .state('tab.search', {
    cache: true,
    url: '/search',
    params: tabParams,
    views: {
      'tab-search': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/tab-search.html',
        controller: 'SearchCtrl'     
      }
    }
  })
```

In my services.js file, that holds all the factory functions that talk to my api server I am defining the headers for the $http sessions as such:

```
  var headers = {
    'Pragma' : 'no-cache', 
    'Expires' : -1, 
    'Cache-Control' : 'no-cache,must-revalidate', 
    'Content-Type' : 'application/json',        
    'X-Requested-With' : 'com.mydomain',
    Authorization : 'Token ' +clientToken[0]
  } ; 
  var baseUrl = "https://api.mydoamin.com/v1/" +appBaseVer+ "/" +apiFile ;  
  var req = {
    method: 'POST',
    url: baseUrl,
    headers: headers,
    data: JSON.stringify(dataObj)
  }  
  return $http(req)
  .then(function(response) {
     ... 
  }) ;
```

And then on my apache server, I am handling the CORS connections in the `.htaccess` file as:

```
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "GET, POST, OPTIONS"
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "Pragma, Expires, Cache-Control, Content-Type, X-Requested-With, Authorization"
Header always set Access-Control-Expose-Headers "Content-Security-Policy, Location"
Header always set Content-Security-Policy "upgrade-insecure-requests;"
Header always set Access-Control-Max-Age: 86400
```

My goal is to have the app do the CORS preflight once for the duration of the app session - caching it using the `Access-Control-Max-Age: 86400`.  But it appears the CORS preflight cache isn't being used when changing between views or going to back a view that was already cached.

Example:

- App View 1: CORS preflight occurs, data is pulled from the server (server page: getInfo.php).  While on that view I can navigate to subviews and back to the parent view and refresh the parent view - and the CORS preflight does not happen again.  This is the desired outcome.
- App View 2: A server call is required for different info (server page: searchInfo.php).  The CORS preflight happens again, but this is not what I am expecting.  I not expecting another preflight, my expectation is that it should use the same preflight that already occurred during `App View 1`.  While on App View 2 and sub views or refreshes, the CORS preflight does not happen again.
- Back to App View 1: Refresh the data with a server call and another CORS preflight is triggered.  Not only is it not using the cached CORS preflight between views, its not even using the one from the same cached view that occurred earlier.
- If I stay on any particular view for a few minutes then refresh the data another CORS preflight is triggered - implying the cached CORS preflight has already expired even though I have set the timeout for 24 hours.

All this behavior then begs the question if the different caches between the cordova webview, the $http headers and the server CORS requirements are impacting or overriding each other.  I don't think the Cordova page views are the source, my gut tells me that somehow the $http headers are interfering with the CORS preflight caching.

Comment: The browser engine from Chrome clamps caching for preflights to just 10 minutes. The sources hardcode an upper limit for it of 600 seconds (10 minutes) — no matter what larger value you specify.

Comment: @sideshowbarker - is this the same for cordova webviews?  I am using the `cordova-plugin-ionic-webview` in my app for both android and ios.  Aside from these limits, my problems still persist even well under the 10min mark.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you're expecting the preflight for one resource to be cached and used for another resource (`view2` using the preflight for `view1`)? Preflights don't apply to an entire domain, they only apply to a single resource (URL).

Comment: See also the answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/42132917/441757

Comment: @KevinChristopherHenry - thanks for both those responses.  Yes, this is what I was looking for.  Well, I was looking for a way to have one cache apply to multiple resources/urls - but understanding this now explains a lot.  I kept reading, incorrectly, that it can be called once - cached - and then used across all the sessions/urls until the cache expired.  I have been banging my head against a wall based on an incorrect understanding.

Comment: @sideshowbarker - thanks, that reinforces what Kevin Christopher Henry replied with.